# Assign & Print Variable in Microsoft VB for Applications

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, variables, vbscript

Very straight forward question.

I have a VB query and I want to assign the 'result' as a variable so that I can then call that variable in later in the script similar to how I would define:

```
<?php 
    $var="variable"
    echo $var;
    $var2 = $var*2;
?>
```

I have the query:

```
Debug.Print "SELECT Min(Field4) AS min_value FROM Market"
```

Is it possible to assign the value from the above query as a variable in the similar method and be able to call it in later? Furthermore, can I also print/echo the value?

Thanks all.

-----------------------------Edit @ 1394754463 for @Rich-----------------------------

This is my current code:

```
Dim output_variable, cn, rs, strquery
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
'----------------------example connection string----------------
 .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
  .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\market.csv" & _
  ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;"""
.Open
'---------------------------------------------------------------
End With
strquery = "SELECT Min(Field4) AS min_value FROM Market"
Set rs = cn.Execute(strquery)
Do While Not rs.EOF
  For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name, rs.Fields(i).Value
    output_variable = CLng(rs.Fields(0).Value)
  Next
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! First you need to connect to the database, then query the information, then iterate through the results **even if it's a 1 value response**.

I didn't know your connection string, so I used a connection string for an excel document instead. For further instructions on connection strings use this website -> [Here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

the output_variable = clng(result) because I don't know if it's an integer or decimal. if it's a decimal, use cdbl() instead.

```
Dim output_variable, cn, rs, strquery
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
'----------------------example connection string----------------
 .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
  .ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\test.xls " & _
  ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"""
.Open
'---------------------------------------------------------------
End With
strQuery = "SELECT Min(Field4) AS min_value FROM Market"
Set rs = cn.Execute(strQuery)
Do While Not rs.EOF
  For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name, rs.Fields(i).Value
    output_variable = clng(rs.Fields(0).Value)
  Next
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Code obtained and revised from -> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955061/vba-adodb-excel-read-data-from-recordset)

---

**EDIT**

Use this connection string for a basic text file reader.

```
Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=c:\txtFilesFolder\;
Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;
```

--or-- use this connection string for a comma delimited registry setting connection string.

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\txtFilesFolder\;
Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";
```

Comment: Hi @Rich, you're a legend. I have managed to fix a few issues regarding the connection string, however, my VB tells me that 

    "'Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)';'C:\market.csv' is not a valid path."
                 Would you have any idea how I can fix this or have I used the wrong connection string? (string added above)

Comment: Well its looking for an xls file, and a csv is just a text file with each row seperated by commas. Try saving the file as xls. Or, google "vba iterate through csv" and avoid the ADO abjects altogether.

Comment: I have saved the file out as an XLS file and still find that the I have a problem in `Set rs = cn.Execute(strquery)` as `...could not find the object 'Market'...`. Have I missed something? (again, thanks)

Comment: Nah you havent missed anything. Driving right now. Give me a bit.