# Issues with looping through recordset, trying to find match between data and database records

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm very new to SQL and the whole ADO enviroment. What I'm trying to do is to see if a string is already in an ID table. The results show up just fine when I use the range.copyfromrecordset method. 
But when I loop through the code I cannot find the string in the fields and rows somehow.

When using recordset.recordcount it gives -1. The String "SWED-A.ST" is in the ID table which I'm accessing and retrieving successfully, but how do I loop through the recordset and show it in the immediate window with debug.print? I've tried to loop through the fields by using a loop and movenext but only the table-heading "ID" shows up....

Code

```
Sub Macro1() ' Tester Sub

    Dim TickerID As String: TickerID = "SWED-A.ST"
    Dim SQLString As String: SQLString = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Instruments WHERE ID = '" & TickerID & "'"

    Dim ADODBBuilder As ADODBBuilder: Set ADODBBuilder = New ADODBBuilder
    Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet: Set RecordSet = ADODBBuilder.ReturnRecordset(TickerID, , , SQLString)

Public Function ReturnRecordset(Optional TickerID As String, Optional startdate As Date, Optional enddate As Date, Optional CustomSQLString As String) As ADODB.RecordSet

Const ConnectionPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\DataBase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim DataConnection As ADODB.Connection: Set DataConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet: Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet

    DataConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionPath
    DataConnection.Open

    If Len(CustomSQLString) > 0 Then
        SQLString = CustomSQLString
    Else
         If Sheets("Mainwindow").Btn_CurrentTime.Value = True Then
            SQLString = "SELECT * FROM " & TickerID _
            & " WHERE [Date] BETWEEN #" & startdate & "# AND #" & enddate & "#"
        Else
            SQLString = "SELECT * FROM " & TickerID
        End If
    End If

    With RecordSet
        .ActiveConnection = DataConnection
        .Source = SQLString
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    Set ReturnRecordset = RecordSet

    'Cleanup
    Set RecordSet = Nothing
    Set DataConnection = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: You could use a reader.  some googleing should should turn up how to use it.  Also, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955061/vba-adodb-excel-read-data-from-recordset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ADO `.Open` uses an `adOpenForwardOnly` cursor that always returns a `.RecordCount` of -1. You are also specifying adOpenForwardOnly in the recordset properties. You need to change it to `adOpenStatic` or `adOpenKeyset` to get an accurate record count returned.

```
DataConnection.Open, adOpenStatic
 ···
With RecordSet
    .ActiveConnection = DataConnection
    .Source = SQLString
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .Open
End With
```

Comment: It still remains though why I can't find the matching string when I loop through the recordset.

Comment: Your select statement uses `SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ...` which is only going to return a maximum of 1 record (TOP 1) and only 1 field (ID). If you want more fields and more records then you need something like `SELECT * FROM ...`.

Comment: The result when using TOP 1 and * are the same. If I use range.copyfromrecordset the target string is there in both cases. I just can't seem to get to it when looping through the recordset....

Comment: Okay, so I was using the .name property. Which apparently seems to return the column name and not the value name, everything was alright from the beginning. Thanks Jeeped!