# Using an array or dictionary as from clause in sql in excel vba

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Is it possible to use an array or dictionary as the table in a SQL statement.

e.g.
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & myArray & ""

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not in VBA.  VB.NET has Linq which is _like_ SQL.  SQL is for querying _databases_, not local variables.  What would you expect the output to be?  If you already have an array what do you need the SQL for?

Comment: Paste the array to an empty sheet and then use ADO to query the sheet. Here is a solution with sample code for your consideration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955061/vba-adodb-excel-read-data-from-recordset

Comment: That was only a rough example the actually sql would have WHERE and GROUP BY clauses, possibly with multiple sql statements being run across the data.

Comment: What do you want to do at all? What would be the desired query? Normally you should use `Join` to link tables. If you would prepend the tables comma separated you would create a cartesian product of all possible combinations of rows between all tables.

Comment: Thanks Ralph but this is being deployed as an XLA so i wanted to keep writing to a sheet to a minimum

Comment: Hi Tim, an example of the desired query would be "SELECT A, B, C FROM " & myArray & " WHERE B = 2. Frankly i don't even know if what i want to do is possible. The array is also 2 dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding upon the idea provided by @Nathan_Sav the following code should to it:

```
Dim a(3) As String

a(0) = "1 as C1"
a(1) = 2
a(2) = 3
a(3) = 4

Debug.Print "select * from (SELECT " & Join(a, " UNION ALL SELECT ") & ") as tmp"
```

### Update:

Here is a short sub to manually concatenate / construct the necessary string:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tmpTest()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim varArray As Variant
Dim lngRow As Long, lngColumn As Long

varArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:G12")

strSQL = "select * from "
strSQL = strSQL & "(select "
For lngRow = LBound(varArray, 1) + 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
    For lngColumn = LBound(varArray, 2) To UBound(varArray, 2)
        'First row must contain column names
        If lngRow = LBound(varArray, 1) + 1 Then
            strSQL = strSQL & varArray(lngRow, lngColumn) & _
                " as [" & varArray(lngRow - 1, lngColumn) & "], "
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & varArray(lngRow, lngColumn) & ", "
        End If
        'Beyond the last column a UNION ALL SELECT must be added
        '  except for the last row
        If lngColumn = UBound(varArray, 2) And _
            lngRow < UBound(varArray, 1) Then
                strSQL = Mid(strSQL, 1, Len(strSQL) - 2) & _
                    " union all select "
        End If
    Next lngColumn
Next lngRow
strSQL = Mid(strSQL, 1, Len(strSQL) - 2) & ") as tmp"
Debug.Print strSQL

End Sub
```

The above code assumes the data to be on sheet1 in the range `A1:G12` where the first row contains the columns headers.

Comment: thx ralph, just to complicate matters the array is 2 dimensional, so i get a subscript out of range error when i try. Is it possible for this to work on a 2 dimensional array. thx for all your help so far (everyone).

Comment: Sorry Ralph i'm kinda new at this and don't know the etiquette, happy to be pointed in the right direction on that.

Answer (score 2):

SQL array like search function:

```
SELECT TABLEARRAY.*
FROM (
    SELECT P.*
    FROM Person P
    WHERE P.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 18) --This would be your array with ID's
     ) AS TABLEARRAY
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim a(3) As Variant

a(0) = 1
a(1) = 2
a(2) = 3
a(3) = 4

Debug.Print "select * from xyz where id in (" & Join(a, ",") & ")"
```

Comment: The array is the table and not a where-clause. If anything you will have to construct the table with `UNION ALL`. So, maybe something like this: `Debug.Print "select * from (" & Join(a, " UNION ALL ") & ") as tmp"`

Comment: What do you mean Ralph

Comment: `Debug.Print "select * from (SELECT " & Join(a, " UNION ALL SELECT ") & ") as tmp"` is almost what you want. But it is still missing a column name.

Comment: Ok, So say the columns are "A", "B", "C", these are defined in the first "row" of the array.