# Excel cells and SQL query bridging the two one 1 sheet

Tags: sql, excel

is there any way to link cells/column to the result of a sql query?

basically i have an SQL query in excel, that returns rows of data. for example if the results of the query only populate columns A & B and i would like to manually  add data to column C that is specific to that row of data, how would i do that? each cell in col. C would have to be link to the row so i will move with the row as the data changes etc.

any help would be greatly appreciated

PS. the DB is readonly

Comment: Best solution would be to move the data which is currently only in Excel to the SQL so that you can retrieve all data from the SQL server. If that's not an option then its getting complicated. This depends on single user working on that table / file or multiple users working on that table / file. If more than open copy of that file will ever exist its getting seriously complicated and you'll have to write some VBA code.

Comment: its a read only DB. i could do an insert into a new DB on a different server. How would that look? but i would need to facilitate the insert via excel.

Comment: Since it seems that you cannot move the data to the SQL server this question is way too broad to be answered here and I am voting to close this post. Here is just a **broad** outline of what has to be done: (1) define a single ID to match rows / entries between the SQL table and the table in Excel (2) disable automatic refresh on that table and write your own update routine using VBA (3) virtually provide the data in Excel to the SQL to enable the SQL to return all data together (like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37896889/1153513).