# Is it possible to connect to a database with excel and execute a query without downloading the tables?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am not sure if what I want to do is possible...

I want to be able to connect to a database using the "Connection Wizard" in Microsoft Excel 2010, without copying an entire table into excel.

I need to run a select statement that is using several tables and enter this information into a spreadsheet on it's own.  Is this even possible?

I have tried to use VBA to connect to the database and run my query but I am receiving this error : The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found.  These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3 (or greater) client software.

I have added a reference to Microsoft Active X, but still not working.  I have tried downloading drivers, with no success.  I am able to connect to the database and run a query through Visual Studio, just not with Excel VBA.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875901/ms-excel-join-external-sql-data-with-local-table-sheet/37896889#37896889 It **starts** by pulling a random table from the SQL but then the connection is altered and an SQL-Select is executed instead to pull data from the SQL.

Comment: Are you not able to run a extract from the database, so instead of pulling from excel, push from the database. In this case it is easy enough to specify your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Excel - join external (SQL) data with local table (sheet)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875901/ms-excel-join-external-sql-data-with-local-table-sheet)