# How to create and join multiple temporary tables derived from an access table in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm in a situation where i have to create multiple temporary tables based on different sub setting conditions from an access table and do inner join to create the final table. Can you please suggest me on how to copy the information from  ADO recordsets to temporary tables and perform inner join?

Comment: This has already been asked and replied I think. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3955529/78522 (and there are others)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little sample you can start with:

```
Sub SQLCombineExample()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
           "DriverId=790;" & _
           "Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
           "DefaultDir=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";ReadOnly=False;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = con.Execute("select distinct a.test1, b.test3 from [Sheet1$] as a , [Sheet1$] as b ")
    Range("f1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Actually I am looping through an access database and creating multiple recordsets, as I cannot execute SQL queries on recordsets I am thinking about creating temporary tables and perform inner join on them. It seems that you are suggesting me to copy data to excel and perform joins, is there any other way where in i can store data in memory only?