# How to Write Select Query and Fetch Details to Excel |VBA|

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a Query Where I Need to Add **Query Statement** and fetch that Details to the Excel Sheet

Table name is : **Student_Details**

```
ID|Name|Course|
1 |vik |MBA   |
2 |sik |CA    |
3 |mil |CP    |
4 |hil |MP    |

query : Select * from Student_Details;
```

How Do I implement in Below Query

```
Sub Ora_Connection()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'---  Replace below highlighted names with the corresponding values

strCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
"(HOST=ora130b-example.intra)(PORT=1534))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=JFG))); uid=jfg_o; pwd=ure;"
'---  Open the above connection string.

con.Open (strCon)
'---  Now connection is open and you can use queries to execute them.
'---  It will be open till you close the connection

con.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should make it work** Taken from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955529/5720144)

**Steps:**

- Set the results and Execute the Query
- Print those result in a loop.

---

```
con.Open (strCon)

query = "Select * from Student_Details"
Set rs = con.Execute(query)

Do While Not rs.EOF
  For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name, rs.Fields(i).Value
  Next
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close


con.Close
```

---

**To directly copy data to Activesheet Use:**

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```